# How to create a dynamic Nav using NgbNavModule and ng-content dynamic?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nav, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to create a dynamic navigation with [NgbNavModule](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/releases/11.x/#/components/nav/overview) that can receive child components in the **ngbNavContent**, I am trying to use **ng-content** but I am not able to achieve it, I am not able to do it using **ngTemplateOutlet** either

**parent-ts**

```js
items = [{title: "secondTitle",navName: "test-first"},
      {title: "firstTitle", navName: "test-second"}];
```

**parent-html**

```html
<generic-component [items]="items">
  <ng-container test-first>
    <first-child-component> </first-child-component>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container test-second>
    <second-child-component> </second-child-component>
  </ng-container>
</generic-component>
```

**generic-component-ts:**

```js
@Input() items;
```

**generic-component-html:**

```html
<ul ngbNav #navDirectDebitPayment="ngbNav" 
  [activeId]="1"
  [destroyOnHide]="false">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
    <li [ngbNavItem]="i + 1">
      <a ngbNavLink>
        {{item.title}}
      </a>
      <ng-template ngbNavContent>
        <ng-content select="[id=item.navName]"></ng-content>
      </ng-template>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
<div [ngbNavOutlet]="navDirectDebitPayment"></div>
```